# I've deleted all initramfs files (like an idiot) How to restore them?

Tags: boot, kernel, initramfs

I've been having an issue where when ever my computer hard resets it will fail to boot on the next start up, usually complaining about initramfs iirc. I've gotten around it up till now, i think usually by booting into a older kernal version (?) at start up, but I can't remember for sure.

Regardless, it was for this reason that when it happened most recently and I discovered the update-initramfs tool I thought I would use the delete option to delete them (I should have looked up what initramfs does, thought it was optional, dumb.) The kernal version I have on that partition is 5.8.0-38-generic.

I have multiple disks and can boot onto a different one for the time being. I tried using update-initramfs on this one to create a file but it
gave the following error:

````
WARNING: missing /lib/modules/5.8.0-38-generic
Ensure all necessary drivers are built into the linux image!
depmod: ERROR: could not open directory /lib/modules/5.8.0-38-generic: No such file or directory
depmod: FATAL: could not search modules: No such file or directory
depmod: WARNING: could not open /var/tmp/mkinitramfs_EKNhXF/lib/modules/5.8.0-38-generic/modules.order: No such file or directory
depmod: WARNING: could not open /var/tmp/mkinitramfs_EKNhXF/lib/modules/5.8.0-38-generic/modules.builtin: No such file or directory```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [tutorial](https://linoxide.com/linux-how-to/fixing-broken-initrd-image-linux/) will walk you through rebuilding. To summarize the steps in the tutorial:

1. Boot your machine with a Live Media
2. Open a terminal console and get partitions path
3. Mount the filesystems
4. Chroot /mnt and creating a Backup of the initrd image
5. Building Initrd Image
6. Finalizing Grub Loader and unmounting

Note because you have other partitions you can boot with you can likely skip step 1.

Comment: Hey there, 
thank you for the quick reply. In step 5. (Building the initrd image) I get that same error I posted about originally:
```...
W: missing /lib/modules/5.8.0.41-generic
```

Comment: I gave it the argument "all" for the version and it looks like it built 5.8.0.38-generic first and then built 5.8.0.41-generic successfully. I'll restart and see if it works. Thanks again :)

Comment: @jboon Let us know it works. Better yet click the grey checkmark next to the answer that solves the problem so others know what to do. Thanks.

Comment: I've "check-marked" the answer. There is one caveat, I had to specify "all" as the version when building the initrd image. When I specified 5.8.0.41 it failed.